# How can I show a label for a certain field in an attribute table for a shapefile?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, idle

```
names = ["Schools"]
layers = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "*", df)

for layer in layers:
  if layer.name == "Schools":
    layer.showLabels = True
```

My code labels the default field in the attributes table. I want it to label a field in the Schools shapefile called "Name_Type" instead of the default field.

Comment: Have a look at the layer objects' labelclasses http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/LabelClass/00s30000002t000000/ to label other than the default class.

Answer (score 3):

You can use labelClasses to do it.

---

```
layers = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "*", df)

for layer in layers:
  if layer.name == "Schools":
    layer.showLabels = True
    lblClass=layer.labelClasses[0]
    lblClass.expression="[Name_Type]"
```